# Can Sitecore 10 Content Serialization serialize users and roles?

Tags: serialization, scs

I am trying to figure out if Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS) can be used instead of the Unicorn.
The only thing I don't see so far is that if SCS can serialize Users and Roles?
Is it possible at the moment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not yet supported but is in the roadmap. (I am the Product Manager for the Sitecore CLI.)

The documentation for the CLI and Sitecore Content Serialization is found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/sitecore-content-serialization.html

This documentation is for the "legacy" serialization functionality, which is accessed via the Developer toolbar.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-manager/en/serialize-an-item-or-a-tree-of-items-484805.html

Comment: Great! We just ran into a use case where we need that for our client.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Sitecore 10 documentation, yes - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-manager/en/serialize-an-item-or-a-tree-of-items-484805.html.

> You can serialize security entities. You can configure predicates to filter which users and roles are serialized.

Answer (score 0):

We also had same requirement to serialize Security entities. We are able to serialize using 'Legacy' way of serialization as @nickwesselman mentioned here. Below are the steps.
[image]
But Sitecore stores serialized files in default format such as .user for Users and .role for Roles. But we need in YML format. For that we changed the `SerializationType` to `YAML` format in below config `App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Serialization.config` (We created a patch for this change as Sitecore recommendation)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you track it down in the source control then using serialization?

Comment: While you are configuring Sitecore CLI against root of your Solution path, create a folder under Solution root. So when you are doing pull/push operations using SC CLI,  content will be serialized into that folder from which you can check-in/check-out the serialized items with source control.